# Script fails to load each and every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I use the following code to load an external HTML file containing code for a slideshow script called Flexisel:

```
    // ==UserScript==

// @run-at      document-start

// ==/UserScript==

$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "/JS/jquery.flexisel.js.html",
           success: function(){},
           dataType: "script",
           cache: false
        });

$(window).load(function() {
    $("#flexisel").flexisel({
        visibleItems: 5,
        animationSpeed: 1000,
        autoPlay: true,
        autoPlaySpeed: 2000,            
        pauseOnHover: true,
        enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
        responsiveBreakpoints: { 
            portrait: { 
                changePoint:480,
                visibleItems: 1
            }, 
            landscape: { 
                changePoint:640,
                visibleItems: 2
            },
            tablet: { 
                changePoint:768,
                visibleItems: 3
            }
        }
    });
 });
```

This code works great when the user first visits the site or visits a page they haven't visited before. Unfortunately there are instances when the slideshow fails to load e.g. when the user clicks the back button in the browser. Is there a more reliable solution to ensure that this code is always loaded correctly?

I have the following limitations:

I have to use this approach because I am using a custom ecommerce solution which is very limited in features. I can upload files for instance using Tiny MCE (but only limited file types). This is why I am using an HTML file containing the JS code and not a JS file.

I have no direct control over the layout or template used for the page.

I can create custom CSS and JavaScript scripts but I have no control over the sequence of when these are loaded (i.e. I can't position them on the page).

JQuery is installed by default so I do have access to some features (I'm not entirely sure which version).

Any suggestions of a more reliable way to load this code given these limitations would be welcome...

Comment: My suggestion would be to change the custom ecommerce solution

Comment: make script create some element in document. on load check if exist, if not load again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in my opinion is that your ajax response might not load till you run the script, thus the flexisel plugin does not exists at that point of execution (?).

The proper way in my opinion is to hook to the document ready event, or use the shorthand version, and load the flexisel in the ajax response function body:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "/JS/jquery.flexisel.js.html",
     success: function(){
        $("#flexisel").flexisel({
            visibleItems: 5,
            animationSpeed: 1000,
            autoPlay: true,
            autoPlaySpeed: 2000,            
            pauseOnHover: true,
            enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
            responsiveBreakpoints: { 
                portrait: { 
                    changePoint:480,
                    visibleItems: 1
                }, 
                landscape: { 
                    changePoint:640,
                    visibleItems: 2
                },
                tablet: { 
                    changePoint:768,
                    visibleItems: 3
                }
            }
        });
     },
     dataType: "script",
     cache: false
  });
});
```

If this doesn't work, you can still try the window load :)

Answer (score 0):

Force the page to refresh every time before running the script

```
window.location = window.location
```